# Scipy MLE fit of a normal distribution

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

I was trying to adopt this solution proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324222/how-can-i-do-a-maximum-likelihood-regression-using-scipy-optimize-minimize) to determine the parameters of a simple normal distribution. Even though the modifications are minor (based on wikipedia), the result is pretty off. Any suggestion where it goes wrong?

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return 1./(math.sqrt(2.*math.pi)*sig)*np.exp(-np.power((x - mu)/sig, 2.)/2)

def lik(parameters):

    mu    = parameters[0]
    sigma = parameters[1]    
    n     = len(x)  
    L     = n/2.0 * np.log(2 * np.pi) + n/2.0 * math.log(sigma **2 ) + 1/(2*sigma**2) * sum([(x_ - mu)**2 for x_ in x ])

    return L



mu0    = 10
sigma0 = 2

x = np.arange(1,20, 0.1)
y = gaussian(x, mu0, sigma0)


lik_model = minimize(lik, np.array([5,5]), method='L-BFGS-B')


mu    = lik_model['x'][0]
sigma = lik_model['x'][1]

print lik_model

plt.plot(x, gaussian(x, mu, sigma), label = 'fit')
plt.plot(x, y, label = 'data')
plt.legend()
```

Output of the fit:

jac: array([2.27373675e-05, 2.27373675e-05])

message: 'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'

success: True

x: array([10.45000245,  5.48475283])

[image: curve and fit]

Comment: I'd say that your initial sigma is too far from the optimum and then the optimizer doesn't find it. You should give it a smaller value to start with, try out with `1` or lower. This is a very common error when fitting parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum likelihood method is for fitting the parameters of a distribution to a set of values that are purportedly a *random sample from that distribution*.  In your `lik` function, you use `x` to hold the sample, but `x` is a global variable that you have set to `x = np.arange(1,20, 0.1)`.  That is definitely not a random sample from a normal distribution.

Because you are using the normal distribution, you can use the known formulas for the maximum likelihood estimate to check your computation:  mu is the sample mean, and sigma is the sample standard deviation:

```
In [17]: x.mean()
Out[17]: 10.450000000000006

In [18]: x.std()
Out[18]: 5.484751589634671
```

Those value matches the result of your call to `minimize` pretty closely, so it looks like your code is working.

To modify your code to use MLE in the way you expected it to work, `x` should be a collection of values that are purportedly a random sample from a normal distribution.  Note that your array `y` is not such a sample.  It is the value of the probability density function (PDF) on a grid.  If fitting the distribution to a sample of the PDF is your actual goal, you can use an curve-fitting function such as [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).
If fitting the normal distribution parameters to a random sample is, in fact, what you want to do, then to test your code, you should use an input that is a reasonably large sample from a distribution with known parameters.  In this case, you can do

```
x = np.random.normal(loc=mu0, scale=sigma0, size=20)
```

When I use such an `x` in your code, I get

```
In [20]: lik_model.x
Out[20]: array([ 9.5760996 ,  2.01946582])
```

As expected, the values in the solution are approximately 10 and 2.

(If you use `x` for your sample as I did, you'll have to change your
plotting code accordingly.)

Comment: can I write x (the data) as an argument to the function that calculates likelihood?